# XSLT to print values of a node based on its position repetitively

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to transform this sample xml in xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0
**Source XML**

```
<root>
    <group>
        <subgroup>
            <name>AAA1</name>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup>
            <name>AAA2</name>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup>
            <name>AAA3</name>
       </subgroup>
    </group>
 <group>
        <subgroup>
            <name>BB1</name>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup>
            <name>BB2</name>
        </subgroup>
        <subgroup>
            <name>BB3</name>
       </subgroup>
    </group>
</root>
```

**Required XML OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <group>AAA1|BB1|AAA2|BB2|AAA3|BB3</group>
</root>
```

I tried the following xslt:

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <group>
       <xsl:for-each select="group">
          <xsl:for-each select="subgroup">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose> 
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
       </group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current-output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<group>AAA1|AAA2|AAA3BB1|BB2|BB3</group>
</root>
```

How can I do this? Should I create a template a call it recursively?

Comment: Is it known that the groups are equal in size?

Comment: BTW, you have asked 5 questions before this one - but accepted the answer on only one of them. Why is that?

Comment: @michael The number of groups are constant(6). The Spec inside them is dynamic. My bad, I accepted two other questions. One of them is still open.

Comment: "*The number of groups are constant(6). The Spec inside them is dynamic.*" What do you mean by *dynamic*? If the groups are not equal in size - i.e. contain the same number of specs - then the accepted answer will not work. Please clarify.

Comment: There will be exactly six xml group elements. However the number of element "specs" is known only during runtime. Also, if the first group has  specs element 3 times, then the second group will also have it 3 times. Hope I'm clear now.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process just *one* of the sets of `spec` elements, and pull out the corresponding `spec` from the other set by position:

```
<root>
  <group>
    <xsl:for-each select="group[1]/spec">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="../../group">
        <!-- put a | in front of everything but the first spec in the first group -->
        <xsl:if test="$pos &gt; 1 or position() &gt; 1">|</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="spec[$pos]/name" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </group>
</root>
```

---

XSLT 2.0 version: in 2.0 you can do it with a single `value-of`:

```
<group>
  <xsl:value-of select="for $n in 1 to count(group[1]/spec)
                        return (group/spec[$n]/name)" separator="|" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

Picked up the all other groups except the first and then iterated over all specs for first group while picking up the corresponding specs from all other groups

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <group>
        <xsl:variable name="firstExcludeGroups" select="//group[position()!=1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstGroup" select="//group[position()=1]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$firstGroup/spec">
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
          <xsl:variable name="curPosition" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$firstExcludeGroups/spec">
            <xsl:if test="$curPosition=position()">
              <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </group>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```